# iMac from England

Tags: imac

Question: Would I be able to use an iMac from England in Canada.  I am not thinking there would be any problems with the software it is the electrical part of the equation I am concerned with.  Easy enough to get an adapter for the plug but will the difference in voltage and hertz cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be fine as long as you'll use the appropriate plug for your country.

iMacs use a three-pin plug and the internal PSU can be used with electrical outlets used in England as well as in Canada.